# Mesh folding self-collision body?

Tags: physics

I have a folding box mesh.

[image]

When I fold it, it overlapped.

[image]

I want to apply physics collision body such that overlapping will not happen. However, I tried rigidbody and softbod and that didn't solve my problem. What tool should I use to achieve this feat?

Comment: You can consider using an armature and use 'limit rotation' for the bones in it.